# Selection inheritance (::selection, ::-moz-selection)

Tags: html, css, firefox, inheritance, pseudo-element

I can't understand the way `::-moz-selection` pseudo element is inherited. What I mean: is it possible that if I will apply ::-moz-selection to body tag

```
body::moz-selection {
  background: red;
}
```

It will also apply to say paragraph (<p>) inside body tag?
I found this http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-cascade

> This could alternately be described in terms of inheritance. The observable differences would be in how inherit and unset behave. Should it inherit from the parent ::selection or the originating element? Opera does the former, Gecko/Blink the latter.

I don't quite understand what means 'originating' element ('parent' seems to be clear to me) and the way this inheritance works.

Comment: btw, to apply ::-moz-selection to every tag in the document the next is used:
`*::-moz-selection { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS, the *originating element* of a pseudo-element simply refers to the element that the pseudo-element is attached to. For example, in the selector `body::selection`, the originating element is the `body` element.

That note is saying that in Opera (Presto), the `::selection` pseudo-elements of child elements inherit their styles from the `::selection` pseudo-elements of their parents, whereas in Gecko and Blink, they inherit from their originating element *only* (which is the standard behavior for all existing CSS1 and CSS2 pseudo-elements).

It would seem that the cascading behavior of multiple `::selection` styles is well-defined: take the innermost declarations. But inheritance is a sticking point, especially considering the conflicting implementation behavior. In particular, if `color: inherit` were specified on `::selection`, should this value be taken from the originating element's color (behaving exactly like `currentColor`), or should it be taken from its parent's `::selection`?

Comment: Don't worry. You can still mark an answer to your question as the best answer by clicking the checkmark underneath the score. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance behavior of selection has been standardized in the CSS spec but browsers are yet to implement the new selection behavior (as of time of writing). Unfortunately this means more short-term uncertainty and variability in ::selection inheritance.